# Minimize docker container size built with Nix's `dockertools.buildImage`

Tags: python, docker, nix

I'm packing python application into docker with nix's `dockerTools` and all is good except of the image size. Python itself is about 40Mb, and if you add `numpy` and `pandas` it would be few hundreds of megabytes, while the application code is only ~100Kb.

The only solution I see is to pack dependencies in separate image and then inherit main one from it, it won't fix the size, but at least I won't need to transfer huge images on every commit. Also I don't know how to do this, should I use some image with nix, or build environment with `pythonPackages.buildEnv` and the attach my app to it?

It would be great to have some generic solution, but python specific would be good. Even if you have imperfect solution, please share.

Ok, with `fromImage` attr for `buildImage` I split one huge layer into huge dependency layer and small app code layer.
I wonder if there is any way to move this fat dependency layer into separate image, so I could share it among my other projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling a bit and reading `dockerTools` code I ended with this solution:

```
let
  deps = pkgs.dockerTools.buildImage {
    name = "deps";
    content = [ list of all deps here ];
};
in pkgs.dockertools.buildImage {
  name = "app";
  fromImage = deps;
}
```

This will build two layer docker image, one of them would be dependencies, other one is app. Also is seems that value for `fromImage` could be result of `pullImage` which should give you same result (if I understood code correctly), but I wasn't able to check it.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to package your dependencies in a separate image and inherit it, although that can't do harm.

All you need to do is make sure that you add your application code as one of the last steps in the Dockerfile. Each command will have its own layer, so if you only change your application code, all layers above that change can be used from cache.

Example from the [Docker Images and Layers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#images-and-layers.) documentation:

The dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:15.10
COPY . /app
RUN make /app
CMD python /app/app.py
```

contains four distinct layers. If you only modify the last line, only that layer and all layers below that will have to be transferred. When pushing or pulling you will see `4b0ba2c4050a: Already exists` next to the layers being used from cache.
Following this approach you don't end up with a smaller image, but as you say you don't have to pull large images on each change.